# Python and 3D Design

Tags: python, animation, 3d, drawing, layer

I used the program 3ds max during 3D Design and Animation class. I had to know lots of aspects and tools of how to draw different complicated figures, split objects, work with layers etc. Some resulst were good but some not. How can the application of Python programming language improve and simplify creating drawings and animations in 3D Design?

I heard about that Python can be used in 3D design but don't know how to add coding feature in 3ds max and other 3D design programs.